# SSIS Package waiting for me to press enter

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I made an `SSIS` package. When I try to run it from `Visual Studio` this package runs fine, but when I try to run it from command line:

`dtexec /f "S:\ABC\XYZ\SSIS\TradeRev-TradeDate-Load.dtsx" /set "\package.variables[ServerName].Value;newservername"`

Here after executing the command above, it waits for me to press `enter` to execute?

Need help.

Comment: How do you know it waits for you to press Enter? Does it say 'please press enter'? on the command line? Does any other key work? I've never heard of `DTEXEC` waiting for a user response

Comment: it's just wait. If I press any other key it doesn't work. Only Enter key works.

Comment: So you 1. Run the command in a command line window (CMD.EXE) 2. After you press Enter to start the command, there is no change on the screen. 3. When you subsequently press enter, output starts appearing in your command line window

Comment: Correct! all other packages are running fine except this one.

Comment: It's quite puzzling. What is different about this package?

Comment: Nothing here I am using a C# script to replace nulls in flat file and that's it.

Comment: Can you create a package that does nothing with an identical name and variables (i.e. identical command line) and run it, then rename your package to something else and run it. What behaviour do you see?

Comment: Is this a copy and paste error? what if you typed that out in the command window (and not copied/pasted anything)?

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to try moving the quotes like this:

```
dtexec /f "S:\ABC\XYZ\SSIS\TradeRev-TradeDate-Load.dtsx" /set "\package.variables[ServerName].Value";newservername
```

Try that, and let us know :)